# Updating core with Composer doesn't work

Tags: 8, drush, updating

I am on D 8.3.0-rc2 and want to update to D 8.3.0 stable. Composer is my only option (requirement of address module). Composer core update doesn't bring me beyond 8.3-0-rc2, not even forcing it. Running `drush composer require "drupal/core:^8.3@stable"` gives me the following output:

> ./composer.json has been updated
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Nothing to install or update

The content of composer.json is the following.

```
{

"name": "drupal/drupal",
"description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0+",
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.21",
    "drupal/core": "^8.3@stable",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "~1.3",
    "drupal/address": "~1.0",
    "drush/drush": "^8.1"
},
"replace": {
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
},
"extra": {
    "_readme": [
        "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
        "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php."
    ],
    "merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "core/composer.json"
        ],
        "recurse": false,
        "replace": false,
        "merge-extra": false
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
    "post-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess",
    "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
    "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup"
},
"repositories": {
    "drupal": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
}
}
```

I read about deleting vendor and composer.lock, but I don't understand why this would work.

Comment: ive never seen "drush composer". what is it supposed to do?

Comment: It's the Drush command implemented by a module. It just calls Composer.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - So it's the drush command of a module that's used to update the core here? Suspicious...

Comment: @leymannx It's the [Composer](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer) module.

Comment: As I found out, `composer...` works as well (without the `drush` prefix)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to update Drupal directly with Composer, instead try starting with [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) as a starting point. This project definitely works with Drupal 8.3.0.

Set up a new project with drupal-composer/drupal-project, and use `composer require` to add any modules you need. Once your code is the same in the new project as the old, you should be able to just copy the database over (or just point to your existing database with settings.php) and run updatedb.

Comment: If you go this route, you may need to adjust the "installer-paths" to match where your contrib stuff is now.

Comment: Many thanks, @greg_1_anderson - this approach solved my problem (after a loooong composer learning curve and some other project obligations). `drupal-composer/drupal-project` exceeded the memory quota of my hosting plan, but `drupal/drupal` worked :-) Thanks again!

Comment: There is a follow-up question: All contextual menus (symbol in upper right of block) still contain the path of the build directory - not even updated by clearing all caches. Using the links (e.g. edit, edit view, etc.) causes fatal errors. Any idea where this information is stored and can be set to the current path?

Comment: My solution approach (there are very likely simpler ways...): 1) run create-project; 2) copy the code BEFORE calling it to set up Drupal; 3) export the "hot" database; 4) call Drupal in the target location to set it up (resets the DB!); 5) re-import the database

Answer (score 0):

You already have the right version in your composer.json. Then it's just `composer install` (in your case it's `drush composer install`).

If that not works, delete your lock file and/or the vendor folder prior to calling `composer install` (or `drush composer install`).

And I guess `composer update drupal/core` (in your case `drush composer update drupal/core`) might work as well (since the version in your lock file or in the vendor folder is different from that in your composer.jon).

Comment: Thanks @leymannx, it was also my assumption that `update` or `install` should work, but for reasons which I don't understand none of it worked as expected (that's why I posted the request). My guess is that there were quire some internal changes with the update to Drupal 8.3.0 stable there were some "dependency deadlocks". The good news is that `composer...` works as well (instead of `drush composer ...`)