# How do I manually update without using Drush nor Composer?

Tags: updating

Is it possible to upgrade Drupal from 8.3.7 to 8.4 without Drush or Composer?

Even though I have used composer I am not comfortable with using terminal/console command lines operations. So far used composer to install and remove modules. That's about it.

Looked at manual update options. There are no instructions yet for this method. 
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-manually-via-gui-option-1

This is what I am planning on doing.

Download and extract Drupal 8.4 zip.

- Backup database  through PHPMyAdmin and website before
  proceeding.
- Put site in maintenance mode by going to
  configuration -> maintenance mode
- Remove ‘core’ and ‘vendor’   directory project dir.
- Upload the core directory from the Drupal 8.4 version 
  downloaded.
- Upload .htaccess,composer.lock and composer.json files from the downloaded Drupal to project.
- Upload vendor directory from the download
  Drupal version to your project.
- Go to site.com/update

Am I missing something? Or should I figure out the composer route?

Comment: In the Drupal of question, did you use composer to install modules as well?

Comment: You say you've used composer before, but did you use it to install Drupal 8.3.7? If yes, then update with composer. If no, then do a manual update. There are instructions for this, see UPDATE.txt in the core folder of your Drupal installation.

Comment: Haha...sorry. I meant 8.3.7. Manually installed Drupal. Been using Composer here and there for module install.

Comment: Then use Composer to update core. Any other way is painful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am willing to try but my only concern is that if something goes wrong I don't know how to revert the changes. With a manual method I can restore files and DB if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official update method is described in UPDATE.txt:

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/UPDATE.txt?h=8.4.x

This is basically what you've described in the question. You don't need composer to update core.

If you want to switch your existing installation to composer a risk free way would be to start a new project, see [Updating core with Composer doesn't work](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/234389/updating-core-with-composer-doesnt-work/234415#234415).

Comment: Manual update worked just fine.